# Display repeater field of ACF

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, plugins

i´m trying to display a repeater field made of images in my wordpress template but it just doesn´t work. I tried reading the doc of the plugin:
http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/add-ons/repeater-field/
But still can´t make it work.

Here it´s the markup:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <ul id="slides">
        <li><img src="<?php the_repeater_field('home_slider'); ?>" alt="" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The name of the repeater field is "home_slider" and the name of the field is "home_image". Please can someone help me out?

This is what displays after load the page:

```
<img src alt>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The repeater-field stores everything in a array, so you need to retreive it then loop it out, try this:

```
$slides = get_field('home_slider');  // Grabs the array

// Check if there is any data in the array before looping
if($slides) {
     echo '<ul id="slideshow">';
     foreach($slides as $s) {
         echo '<li>';
         echo '<img src="'.$s['home_image'].'" alt="" />';
         echo '</li>';
     }
     echo '</ul>';
}
```

Now depending on what you set the image to return (image url, attachement ID or Image Object ) you will need to use different methods to get the path to the image.

Comment: I set image Image url to return

Comment: Then the above example should do it.

Comment: it still doesn´t show the images... I don´t know what´s happening